llvm error when attempt to build libcxx instrumented with memory sanitizer
I'm trying to fix MemorySanitizer issue @https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/MemorySanitizerLibcxxHowTo. I run:
cmake -GNinja ../llvm \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
    -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="libcxx;libcxxabi" \
    -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang \
    -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ \
    -DLLVM_USE_SANITIZER=MemoryWithOrigins

But got the error:

libcxx isnt a known project, did you mean to enable it as a runtime LLVM_ENABLE_RUNTIMES

How to fix it?
More information about initial problem - under the link:
Using memory sanitizer with libstdc++
My issue is the same - memory sanitizer points to uninitialized values where it should not.

According to that commit, you should follow the advice in the error message and specify libcxx and libcxxabi in the LLVM_ENABLE_RUNTIMES option instead of LLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS one.

that's absolutely right, I've managed to set missing variables to CMakeLists
set(LLVM_ALL_PROJECTS "bolt;clang;clang-tools-extra;compiler-rt;cross-project-tests;libc;libclc;libcxxabi;)

now I'm having last issue here: CMake Error at /home/j/llvm-project/libcxxabi/CMakeLists.txt:52 (message): LIBCXXABI_USE_LLVM_UNWINDER is set to ON, but libunwind is not specified in

last amend I have in CMakeList.txt under ~/llvm-project/llvm
set(LLVM_DEFAULT_RUNTIMES "libcxx;libcxxabi;libunwind")

set(LLVM_SUPPORTED_RUNTIMES "libc;libunwind;libcxxabi;pstl;libcxx;compiler-rt;openmp;llvm-libgcc;offload")

set(LLVM_ENABLE_RUNTIMES "libunwind;libcxx;libcxxabi" CACHE STRING
    "Semicolon-separated list of runtimes to build, or \"all\" (${LLVM_DEFAULT_RUNTIMES}). Supported runtimes are ${LLVM_SUPPORTED_RUNTIMES}.")


Solution is below:
~/llvm-project/llvm/CMakeList.txt

set(LLVM_DEFAULT_RUNTIMES "libcxx;libcxxabi;libunwind")
set(LLVM_SUPPORTED_RUNTIMES "libc;libunwind;libcxxabi;pstl;libcxx;compiler-rt;openmp;llvm-libgcc;offload")
set(LLVM_ENABLE_RUNTIMES "libunwind" CACHE STRING

build command:
cmake -GNinja ../llvm      -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release      -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="libcxx;libcxxabi"       -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang    -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++    -DLLVM_USE_SANITIZER=MemoryWithOrigins

second part derived to LLVM Build Fails with MemorySanitizer Enabled
